# If $g(x) = 3x^2+2x-1$, and if $f(x)$ is such that $g(x)=|f(x)|$, then is it possible to find a formula for $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider function $g\left(x\right)=3x^2+2x-1$. Now let's say that there exists a function $f(x)$ such that $g\left(x\right)=\left|f\left(x\right)\right|$. How do I find, if possible, the formula for $f(x)$?

Comment: I have a doubt: In this case, shouldn't we have $g(x)$ a positive function?

Comment: @Na'omi is right! $g(0)=-1\not= |f(0)| \forall f$

Answer (score 0):

So notice that $g(x)$ is negative for a certain interval of $\mathbb{R}$ (find this interval by finding the roots). Let this interval be $J$, and take $S=\mathbb{R}\setminus J$. Now for $A\subset S$, define
$$f(x)=-g(x) \textrm{ for $x\in A$}
\\=g(x) \textrm{ for $x\in A^c$}$$
I would imagine that since there exists a region for which $g$ is negative, $f$ is not defined on that interval.